# Removing deprecation warning from momentjs

Tags: momentjs

I'm using momentjs to work with dates in my project for when a user enters a date in `M/D/YYYY` format to revert to `MM/DD/YYYY` format (e.g. `2/5/2017` to `02/05/2017`). I am also converting any invalid dates or dates greater than today to be reset back to today's date.

```js
element.on("blur", function() {
    var currentDate = moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    var formattedInput;

    if (ctrl.$modelValue !== undefined && ctrl.$modelValue !== "") {

        if(moment(ctrl.$modelValue, "MM/DD/YYYY", true).isValid()) {
            formattedInput = moment(ctrl.$modelValue);
            formattedInput.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
            if (formattedInput.isAfter(currentDate)) {
                ctrl.$setViewValue(currentDate);
                ctrl.$render();
            }
        } else if (moment(ctrl.$modelValue, "M/D/YYYY", true).isValid()) {
            formattedInput = moment(ctrl.$modelValue);
            formattedInput.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
            if (formattedInput.isAfter(currentDate)) {
                ctrl.$setViewValue(currentDate);
                ctrl.$render();
            } else {
                ctrl.$setViewValue(formattedInput.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
                ctrl.$render();
            }
        } else {
            ctrl.$setViewValue(currentDate);
            ctrl.$render();
        }
    }
});
```

As far as I can tell, this is all working fine with the code I have above. But regardless of working functionality, I am receiving the deprecation warning for non-ISO dates. My thoughts are the use of `MM/DD/YYYY` format, however this is unchangeable due to business requirements. Is there a way to remedy this issue in a non-cumbersome way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `formattedInput = moment(ctrl.$modelValue)` here you are using moment parsing without format with non-ISO dates. To remove the *Deprecation warning*, just use `moment(ctrl.$modelValue, "MM/DD/YYYY")` and `moment(ctrl.$modelValue, "M/D/YYYY")` as you have done in the `if` condition.

Your complete code will be the following:

```js
element.on("blur", function() {
  var currentDate = moment();
  var formattedInput;

  if (ctrl.$modelValue !== undefined && ctrl.$modelValue !== "") {

    if(moment(ctrl.$modelValue, "MM/DD/YYYY", true).isValid()) {
      formattedInput = moment(ctrl.$modelValue, "MM/DD/YYYY", true);
      // This line returns a string, but does not assign to value, so it's superfluous
      //formattedInput.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
      if (formattedInput.isAfter(currentDate)) {
         ctrl.$setViewValue(currentDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
         ctrl.$render();
      }
    } else if (moment(ctrl.$modelValue, "M/D/YYYY", true).isValid()) {
      formattedInput = moment(ctrl.$modelValue, "M/D/YYYY", true);
      // see previous comment
      //formattedInput.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
      if (formattedInput.isAfter(currentDate)) {
        ctrl.$setViewValue(currentDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
        ctrl.$render();
      } else {
        ctrl.$setViewValue(formattedInput.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
        ctrl.$render();
      }
    } else {
      ctrl.$setViewValue(currentDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
      ctrl.$render();
    }
  }
});
```

Be sure to fully understand the difference between [moment parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) (build a moment object from a string) and moment [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) (display a string representation of a moment object).

Comment: Wow, I didn't notice that .format() was not returning a moment object. This ended up being the entire root cause of the issue, as my `today` variable was being compared to as a string vs. moment objects in my `.isAfter()` calls. I've since change the code to work by changing `var currentDate = moment()` and only using the `.format()` functions when setting the view value. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're welcome! I didn't notice the today var treated as string, even if you already solve your issue, I've fixed my code example after your comment.